# JS: загрузка содержимого тега script с другой страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть дурацкая задача: подгрузить кое-какие данные, находящиеся на странице *url* в теге *script*.

Если делать через `.load(url + ' script')`, то, согласно документации

> If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed.

это не приносит желаемого результата *(хотя некоторые теги  там, всё же присутствуют: видимо, находящиеся в других тегах)*

Если делать через `.load(url) //без селлектора` или `.get(url)` или `.ajax(url)`, *(что, как я понимаю, примерно одно и то же)* то получаю

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

что ломает некоторые функции страницы, менять которые не в моей власти.
Этот `XMLHttpRequest deprecated`, видимо появляется из-за того, что callback для одного из `.load()` является ещё один `.load()`.

Менять структуру страницы `url` нельзя.

Вот такая ситуёвина)

Как быть-то? Подскажите!

Вот, кстати, структура кода:

```
$(window).on('load', function()
{
  $(element).on('click', function()
  {
    $store.load(url+' sellector', function()
    {
      // обычно хватает того, что тут написано, но
      if (/*что-то не так*/) 
      /*
        то вот тут нужно загрузить содержимое тега <script> из url
      */
    });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт использует `XMLHttpRequest` подключается к файлу `names.php` и достает из него, с тага `<script>` содержимое `src`

```
var regex = /<script\s.*src="(.*)">/g;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "/names.php");
req.onload = (function(){
var m = regex.exec(req.responseText)
console.log(m[1]);
})

req.send();
```

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Comment: В данном случае, это не относится к примеру. 
Поставте и все будет работать. По опыту могу скзать, что это самое оптимальное решение